# WordCloud.process_text vs sklearn's CountVectorizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, word-cloud, countvectorizer

I would like to count the term frequency across the corpus. To do that, there are two ways, which was using `CountVectorizer` and sum in `axis=0` as below.

```
count_vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=cab_tokenizer, ngram_range=(1,2), stop_words=stopwords)
cv_X = count_vec.fit_transform(string_list)
```

Another way is using `WordCloud.process_text()` (see doc [here](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud.process_text)) which will result in term-frequency `dict`. I used stopword from previously `TfIdfVectorizer` using `tfidf_vec.get_stop_words()`.

```
text_freq = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords, collocations=True).process_text(text)
```

The fact that I am using stopwords from the `TfIdfVectorizer`, I am expecting this to behave the same, however, the features/terms I am getting is different (length of the dict is less than `TfIdfVectorizer.get_feature_names()`.

So, I am wondering, what is the different of using one over another? Is one more accurate than the other?

Comment: I see 2 reasons tokens from both methods are different: (1) `cab_tokenizer` and (2) `ngram_range`. You may feed a simple, several-words long string to both classes and see how the output would be different.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, I also add lemmatizer in `cab_tokenizer` so it could be the reason. The `ngram_range=(1,2)` means it analyse up to bigram, which is identical with `collocations=True` on `WordCloud`.